# How to use express.js req.params with typescript

Tags: typescript, express

I have express.js controller and I can't use req.params

The error is `Property 'id' is missing in type 'ParamsDictionary' but required in type 'IParam'.`

I need to get `id` from param with type string

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express'

interface IParam {
    id: string
}

const Update = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { id }: IParam = req.param // The error occured here
}

export default Update
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main issue is that you're trying to cast `req.params.id` (a string) as `IParam` (an object).

You can typically just use this...

```js
const { id } = req.params;
```

because [Express defines the default params type](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L52) as

```ts
export interface ParamsDictionary {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

Otherwise, you can strongly type the [`Request`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express/index.d.ts#L113) to include your params

```ts
const Update = (req: Request<IParam>, res: Response) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a type assertion here:

```
interface IParam {
    id: string
}

const Update = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { id } = req.param as unknown as IParam
}

export default Update
```

An assertion tells TypeScript that you know what you're doing. Previously, you had a type annotation, so TypeScript was really eager to jump in and check the assignment.

Comment: It still error `Conversion of type 'ParamsDictionary' to type 'IParam' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Property 'id' is missing in type 'ParamsDictionary' but required in type 'IParam'`

Comment: @kennarddh Oh right... I guess then you'd have to use two assertions - one to cast to unknown first... I think there's a better solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, but I would like to leave my contribution. Below is my solution:

```
import { ParamsDictionary as Params } from "express-serve-static-core";

export interface IRequestParams<T extends Params> extends Request {
  params: T;
}
```